# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to get posts from a group (just like in facebook)

Here is my controller function

```
$search_groups = $this->login->searchGroups($ID);
            $data['group'] = $search_groups;
            $group['group_id'] = $this->login->searchGroupID($ID);
            if(is_array($group['group_id']) || is_object($group['group_id'])){
                foreach($group['group_id'] as $object){
                    $data['home_contents'] = $this->login->showPost($object);
                }
            }
```

This is where it errors. This is my model

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from posts INNER JOIN groups ON groups.group_id = posts.group_ID INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.ID = posts.ID WHERE groups.group_id = "'. $group_id .'"');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
```

The error is on my query. 
The error is

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

I tried var_dump($group); and this is what it shows

```
array(1) { ["group_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["group_id"]=> string(1) "1" } } }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: where exactly is the error?? model r controller?

Comment: That var dump has nothing with error. What was expected result?

Comment: sorry. i forgot to add the error. it's there now

Comment: There are plenty SO questions on this topic, none of them helped you?

Comment: You are not showing us how the first code snippet is related to the second.  Where is the `return $query->result()`  returned to? Do you understand that `result()` returns an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your variable "$group_id" is an object, you can check with print_r how it looks and then change script based on that.